# Como manter selecionado os resultados do meu select após reload de página

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Sou novo em programação e estou com a seguinte situação. Tenho um select2, com algumas cidades selecionadas. Como posso fazer para que quando eu clicar na minha URL e apertar o enter, ele não limpe essas cidades selecionadas?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue meu código abaixo. Essa funcionalidade está em branco no meu código, pois não tenho a menor ideia de como fazer. Não quero fazer isso clicando em um botão, pois já sei fazer. O que eu preciso é que ele não limpe as minhas cidades selecionadas quando eu seleciono a URL e aperto enter. Isso é possível de se fazer?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Cidades</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/4.6.1/css/bootstrap.css" integrity="sha512-Ty5JVU2Gi9x9IdqyHN0ykhPakXQuXgGY5ZzmhgZJapf3CpmQgbuhGxmI4tsc8YaXM+kibfrZ+CNX4fur14XNRg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="card card_primary">
        <div class="card-body">
        <select class="js-example-basic-multiple form-control" id="cboCidades" multiple="multiple" style="width: 100%;">
                <option value="scs">São Caetano do Sul</option>
                <option value="sa">Santo André</option>
                <option value="sbc">São Bernardo do Campo</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div> 

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/4.6.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-UR25UO94eTnCVwjbXozyeVd6ZqpaAE9naiEUBK/A+QDbfSTQFhPGj5lOR6d8tsgbBk84Ggb5A3EkjsOgPRPcKA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2({
            language: "pt-BR",
        });
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Você está apertando enter na barra de endereços do navegador? Se sim, o que está acontecendo é o reload da página. Não tem como impedir.

Comment: Obrigado Felipe Carriel. Sim, isso. Um reload de página. Queria evitar que isso acontecesse, em uma situação específica, no caso limitando uma busca de 5 cidades,  e não a todo momento. Pq qdo ele selecionar mais de 5 cidades, ele colocará essas cidades na URL e manter as cidades selecionadas no Select. Consegui fazer isso clicando por um botão. Queria fazer isso clicando na URL tb.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Provavelmente a sua questão pode-se resolver com cookies. Eles não impedem o reload da página, mas conseguem guardar os dados.
Os cookies podem ser utilizados da seguinte maneira:

```
Criar um cookie/mudar um cookie: document.cookie = "username=John Smith; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2025 12:00:00 UTC; path=/";
Eliminar um cookie: document.cookie = "username=John Smith; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2001 12:00:00 UTC; path=/"; (igual, só que a data já expirou)
Saiba mais sobre cookies => https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp
```

Então, o problema resolve-se da seguinte maneira:

1. Quando a página carrega, cria o cookie ou, se ele já existe, atualiza as informações do input
2. Quando algo muda no input, muda o nome do cookie

E pronto!
Espero ter resolvido o seu problema,

Tiago R.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Tiago. Não consegui entender muito bem em como aplicá-lo em meu problema.

Comment: De nada, @FabricioRezende! Poderia por favor marcar a minha resposta como a solução e/ou votar nela?

Comment: Ficaria imensamente agradecido